# Bash script: Program with parameters as a single variable: command not found

Tags: bash, scripts

I wrote the bash script below (called hdmi_output) and it's working in most parts as I expect it.

For example, I run `hdmi_output run firefox` and Firefox is started on the external monitor.

But sometimes I want to run programs with arguments and this doesn't work anymore. E.g. when running `hdmi_output run "firefox -P -no-remote"`, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/vglrun: 296: exec: **firefox -P -no-remote: not found
```

I wrote it in quotes to be treated as one variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help me to improve the script, maybe `shift` command should be used?

```
#!/bin/bash

start_hdmi() {
...
...
}

run_hdmi() {
    DISPLAY=:8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH optirun "$@"
}

if [[ "$@" == "start" ]]; then
    start_hdmi
elif [[ "$#" == "2" && "$1" == "run" ]]; then
    run_hdmi "$2"
else
    echo "$0 start|run <program>"
fi
```

Comment: This is not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: @con-f-use `bash` scripting questions are almost always considered on topic here; I see no reason why this should be one of the very rare exceptions. Furthermore, some details here vary from one Unix-like OS to another, making this even more clearly on-topic for our site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the double quotes here `run_hdmi "$2"`

Comment: cool, that was easy :)
Is it also possibe to not use quotes when running the script?

Comment: Obviously, no. Because the script will take only the name of a program then.

Comment: For sure, but with further modifications of the script it would be possible, wouldn't it?

Comment: May be.) Modify.